# _grokparsefailure on varnish log

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Message looks like

```
1.2.3.4 "-" - - [19/Apr/2016:11:42:18 +0200] "GET http://monsite.vpù/api/opa/status HTTP/1.1" 200 92 "-" "curl - API-Player - PREPROD" hit OPA-PREPROD-API - 0.000144958
```

My grok pattern is

```
grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{IP:clientip} \"%{DATA:x_forwarded_for}\" %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) %{QS:referrer} %{QS:agent} (%{NOTSPACE:hitmiss}|-) (%{NOTSPACE:varnish_conf}|-) (%{NOTSPACE:varnish_backend}|-) %{NUMBER:time_firstbyte}"}
    }
```

I have a grokparsefailure tag whereas all my fields are fulfilled correctly except for the last one, I get 0 instead of 0.000144958

The full message in ES is

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2016.04.19",
  "_type": "syslog",
  "_id": "AVQt7WSCN-2LsQj9ZIIq",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "212.95.71.201 \"-\" - - [19/Apr/2016:11:50:12 +0200] \"GET http://monsite.com/api/opa/status HTTP/1.1\" 200 92 \"-\" \"curl - API-Player - PREPROD\" hit OPA-PREPROD-API - 0.000132084",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-04-19T09:50:12.000Z",
    "type": "syslog",
    "host": "212.95.70.80",
    "tags": [
      "_grokparsefailure"
    ],
    "application": "varnish-preprod",
    "clientip": "1.2.3.4",
    "x_forwarded_for": "-",
    "ident": "-",
    "auth": "-",
    "timestamp": "19/Apr/2016:11:50:12 +0200",
    "verb": "GET",
    "request": "http://monsite.com/api/opa/status",
    "httpversion": "1.1",
    "response": "200",
    "bytes": "92",
    "referrer": "\"-\"",
    "agent": "\"curl - API-Player - PREPROD\"",
    "hitmiss": "hit",
    "varnish_conf": "OPA-PREPROD-API",
    "varnish_backend": "-",
    "time_firstbyte": "0.000132084",
    "geoip": {
      "ip": "1.2.3.4",
      "country_code2": "FR",
      "country_code3": "FRA",
      "country_name": "France",
      "continent_code": "EU",
      "region_name": "C1",
      "city_name": "Strasbourg",
      "latitude": 48.60040000000001,
      "longitude": 7.787399999999991,
      "timezone": "Europe/Paris",
      "real_region_name": "Alsace",
      "location": [
        7.787399999999991,
        48.60040000000001
      ]
    },
    "agentname": "Other",
    "agentos": "Other",
    "agentdevice": "Other"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1461059412000
    ]
  },
  "highlight": {
    "agent": [
      "\"curl - API-Player - @kibana-highlighted-field@PREPROD@/kibana-highlighted-field@\""
    ],
    "varnish_conf": [
      "OPA-@kibana-highlighted-field@PREPROD@/kibana-highlighted-field@-API"
    ],
    "application": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@varnish@/kibana-highlighted-field@-@kibana-highlighted-field@preprod@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "message": [
      "1.2.3.4 \"-\" - - [19/Apr/2016:11:50:12 +0200] \"GET http://monsote.com/api/opa/status HTTP/1.1\" 200 92 \"-\" \"curl - API-Player - @kibana-highlighted-field@PREPROD@/kibana-highlighted-field@\" hit OPA-@kibana-highlighted-field@PREPROD@/kibana-highlighted-field@-API - 0.000132084"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1461059412000
  ]
}
```

The answer is that kibana do not display very little number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from the syslog filter using grok internally as explained here https://kartar.net/2014/09/when-logstash-and-syslog-go-wrong/.
The solution was then to remove the tag in my own filter

The other problem is that kibana do not display number like 0.0000xxx but they are correctly stored anyway so I can use it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You would only get a grokparsefailure if the grok, um, fails.  So, it's not this grok that's producing the tag.  Use the tag_on_failure parameter in your groks to provide a unique tag for each grok.

As for your parsing problem, I'll bet that your grok is working just fine.  Note that elasticsearch can make fields dynamically and will guess as to the type of the field based on the first data seen.  If your first data was "0", it would have made the field an integer and later entries would be cast to that type.  You can pull the mapping to see what happened.

You need to control the mapping that is created.  You can specify that the field is a float in the grok itself (%{NUMBER:myField:int}) or by creating your own template.

Also notice that NOTSPACE matches "-", so your patterns for varnish_backend, etc, are not entirely correct.

Comment: Thanks Alain, I did remove all my index to have new created index. Now the mapping is correct (it was string) for time_firstbyte but still '0' and grokparsefailure. I also applied your idea (:int)

Comment: The website http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result confirm my grok pattern as OK (see image)

Comment: I try your idea `grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{IP:clientip} \"%{DATA:x_forwarded_for}\" %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) %{QS:referrer} %{QS:agent} (%{NOTSPACE:hitmiss}|-) %{USERNAME:varnish_conf} %{USERNAME:varnish_backend} %{NUMBER:time_firstbyte:int}"}
      tag_on_failure => ["_grokparsefailure_varnish"]` but my grok message is still _grokparsefailure
`

Comment: If you added a distinct tag_on_failure to this grok{} but are still getting the generic "_grokparsefailure" then it is, indeed, a *different* grok that is failing.